Transforming a column to counts according the distinct values of another column in pandas dataframe
I have a panads dataframe from wiki
Outlook  Temperature    Humidity    Wind    Play
Sunny    Hot            High        False   No
Sunny    Hot            High        True    No
Overcast Hot            High        False   Yes
Rainy    Mild           High        False   Yes
Rainy    Cool           Normal      False   Yes
Rainy    Cool           Normal      True    No
Overcast Cool           Normal      True    Yes
Sunny    Mild           High        False   No
Sunny    Cool           Normal      False   Yes
Rainy    Mild           Normal      False   Yes
Sunny    Mild           Normal      False   Yes
Overcast Mild           High        True    Yes
Overcast Hot            Normal      False   Yes
Rainy    Mild           High        True    No

and I want to see if the outlook is sunny/overcast/rainy, how many times are they gonna play and then to calculate the Shannon entropy for each of the outcome, so the desire outcome looks like
Outlook     Yes No  Count of each group Entropy
sunny       2   3   5                   0.971
overcast    4   0   4                   0.000
rainy       3   2   5                   0.971

where Entropy is given by the formula -((yes/count)log_2(yes/count) + (no/count)log_2(no/count))
So for example, the entropy for sunny is -((2/5)log_2(2/5)+(3/5)log_2(3/5))=0.971

You can use a crosstab or pivot_table

The base is a crosstab, you then need to post-process it:
def entropy(yes, no, count):
    return -((yes/count)*np.log2(yes/count) + (no/count)*np.log2(no/count))

out = (pd.crosstab(df['Outlook'], df['Play'], margins=True, margins_name='Count')
         .reindex(columns=['Yes', 'No', 'Count']).drop('Count').rename_axis(columns=None)
         .assign(Entropy=lambda d: entropy(d['Yes'], d['No'], d['Count']).fillna(0))
         .reset_index()
      )

Output:
    Outlook  Yes  No  Count   Entropy
0  Overcast    4   0      4  0.000000
1     Rainy    3   2      5  0.970951
2     Sunny    2   3      5  0.970951


Use : from scipy.stats import entropy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import entropy

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'Outlook': ['Sunny', 'Sunny', 'Overcast', 'Rainy', 'Rainy', 'Rainy', 'Overcast',
                'Sunny', 'Sunny', 'Rainy', 'Sunny', 'Overcast', 'Overcast', 'Rainy'],
    'Temperature': ['Hot', 'Hot', 'Hot', 'Mild', 'Cool', 'Cool', 'Cool', 'Mild', 'Cool', 'Mild', 'Mild', 'Mild', 'Hot', 'Mild'],
    'Humidity': ['High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'High', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'High', 'Normal', 'High'],
    'Wind': [False, True, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, True],
    'Play': ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
'''
     Outlook Temperature Humidity   Wind Play
0      Sunny         Hot     High  False   No
1      Sunny         Hot     High   True   No
2   Overcast         Hot     High  False  Yes
3      Rainy        Mild     High  False  Yes
4      Rainy        Cool   Normal  False  Yes
5      Rainy        Cool   Normal   True   No
6   Overcast        Cool   Normal   True  Yes
7      Sunny        Mild     High  False   No
8      Sunny        Cool   Normal  False  Yes
9      Rainy        Mild   Normal  False  Yes
10     Sunny        Mild   Normal  False  Yes
11  Overcast        Mild     High   True  Yes
12  Overcast         Hot   Normal  False  Yes
13     Rainy        Mild     High   True   No
'''
# Compute counts of Yes, No, and total for each Outlook
outlook_counts = df.groupby('Outlook')['Play'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
'''
Play      No  Yes
Outlook          
Overcast   0    4
Rainy      2    3
Sunny      3    2
'''
outlook_counts['Count'] = outlook_counts.sum(axis=1)
print(outlook_counts)
'''
Play      No  Yes  Count
Outlook                 
Overcast   0    4      4
Rainy      2    3      5
Sunny      3    2      5
'''
# Calculate probabilities
yes_prob = outlook_counts['Yes'] / outlook_counts['Count']
no_prob = outlook_counts['No'] / outlook_counts['Count']

# Calculate entropy using scipy.stats.entropy
outlook_counts['Entropy'] = entropy([yes_prob, no_prob], base=2, axis=0)

# Format the output DataFrame
out = outlook_counts[['Yes', 'No', 'Count', 'Entropy']].reset_index()

print(out)

'''
Play   Outlook  Yes  No  Count   Entropy
0     Overcast    4   0      4  0.000000
1        Rainy    3   2      5  0.970951
2        Sunny    2   3      5  0.970951
'''

